# REACT - useContext state sharing sync issue

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-router

> **Objective : -**

I want the user to be able to see his/her orders only if they are logged in. So I am using AuthContext for state management of users logged in data + tokens.

> **Issue : -**

When I pass down the token from AuthContext to child components, AuthContext takes some time to validate the token with the backend and meanwhile the child component's logic breaks.

> **Child Component (using state/token) :**

```
const MyOrders = () => {
    const { userData } = useContext(AuthContext);
    const history = useHistory();
    if (!userData.token) {      // This redirects the user back to the home page immediately
        history.push("/");      // because the token hasn't been passed yet when
                                // the component is loaded
    };
    const getOrders = async () => {
        const url = 'http://localhost:5000/api/orders';
        try {
            const res = await axios.get(url, {
                headers: {
                    'x-auth-token': userData.token
                }
            });
            console.log(res.data);
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err.response);
        }
    };
    useEffect(() => {
        if (userData.token) getOrders();
    }, []);
```

> **Work Around (is it safe ????)**

```
const MyOrders = () => {
    const token = localStorage.getItem('auth-token');  // Use localStorage token directly instead of 
                                                    // validating the token first (from AuthContext)??
    const history = useHistory();
    if (!token) {      
        history.push("/");                                      
    };

    const getOrders = async () => {
        const url = 'http://localhost:5000/api/orders';
        try {
            const res = await axios.get(url, {
                headers: {
                    'x-auth-token': token
                }
            });
            console.log(res.data);
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err.response);
        }
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        if (userData.token) getOrders();
    }, []);
```

> **Parent Component (AuthContext) :** // in case anyone requires

```
const AuthContextProvider = (props) => {
    const [userData, setUserData] = useState({
        token: undefined,
        user: undefined
    });
    //Need to check if user is logged in
    //every time the App is rendered
    useEffect(() => {
        const checkLoggedIn = async () => {
            const url = "http://localhost:5000/api/users/token";
            let token = localStorage.getItem("auth-token");
            //when user is not logged in
            if(token === null) {
                localStorage.setItem("auth-token", "");
                token = "";
            }
            //need to validate the token if it exists
            const tokenResponse = await axios.post(url, null, {
                headers: { "x-auth-token": token }
            });
            //if token is valid, collect user data 
            if(tokenResponse.data){
                console.log(tokenResponse);
                setUserData({
                    token,
                    user: tokenResponse.data,

                });
            } else {
                localStorage.setItem("auth-token", "");
                token = "";
            };
        };
        checkLoggedIn();                
    }, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can try make a early return just after history.push("/") so rest of the logic will not executed

```
const MyOrders = () => {
    const { userData } = useContext(AuthContext);
    const history = useHistory();
    if (!userData.token) {      // This redirects the user back to the home page immediately
        history.push("/");  
        return (null)
    };
    const getOrders = async () => {
        const url = 'http://localhost:5000/api/orders';
        try {
            const res = await axios.get(url, {
                headers: {
                    'x-auth-token': userData.token
                }
            });
            console.log(res.data);
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err.response);
        }
    };
    useEffect(() => {
        if (userData.token) getOrders();
    }, []);
```

Comment: That's the opposite of what I want. 
I don't want it to go back, I want to show the Orders to the logged in user which I am unable to. Because even if the user is logged in, the useContext provides the token to this child component after a delay and in the meantime, the user gets routed back to the home page.

Comment: you can just remove history.push('/') then when token is updated from AuthContext  MyOrder component will render again. Even you can show 'Loading..' text there

Answer (score 0):

I offer you to try to retrieve the saved token in your first page of the app.
use "await" on the function. after finish trying to retrieve from localStorage,
you should navigate to the login if the token doesn't exist, otherwise navigate to the main page.
In this case you won't have a undefined token if you have a token,

But what if the token is undefined somehow? You need to send an unauthorize error from the server if the user trying to fetch with an undefined token, then catch the error in the client side, check the message and the type you received, if it does an authorization error, navigate to the home page.

It is a little bit complicated answer but it sure solve your problem and it will make it more Clean code and SOLID.

Answer (score 0):

You can add loading to your user data, if setting the user data fails then set loading false and you can redirect in your order by returning a Redirect component from react-router.

```js
const AuthContext = React.createContext();
const AuthContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [userData, setUserData] = React.useState({
    token: undefined,
    user: undefined,
    loading: true,
  });
  React.useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(
      () =>
        setUserData((userData) => ({
          ...userData, //any other data that may be there
          token: 123,
          user: 'Hello world',
          loading: false, //not loading anymore
        })),
      5000 //wait 5 seconds to set user data
    );
  }, []);
  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={userData}>
      {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
};
const App = () => {
  const { loading, ...userData } = React.useContext(
    AuthContext
  );
  if (!loading && !userData.token) {
    //snippet does not have redirect
    //  but if you have react-router you
    //  can do this
    //return <Redirect to="/" />;
  }
  React.useEffect(() => {}, []);
  return loading ? (
    'loading...'
  ) : (
    <pre>{JSON.stringify(userData, undefined, 2)}</pre>
  );
};
ReactDOM.render(
  <AuthContextProvider>
    <App />
  </AuthContextProvider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```